# Bluetooth headset opens Apple Music and starts playing music

Tags: itunes, bluetooth, headphones

My current setup:

- macOS 11.4
- MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2019)
- Jabra Evolve2 65 connected via Bluetooth (not using the included Jabra dongle)

What happens:

- I turn the laptop on then the headset
- Make a call (Typically MS Teams)
- Put the headset down and end the call
- Later on, **move** the headset - not necessarily put it on, just **move** it
- Apple Music launches and starts playing the first track in my library

It's like the headset is saying "since I'm being moved I'm being used so open Apple Music and start playing something."
When I first turn on the headset Apple Music does NOT immediately turn on.  This only happens if it's turned on and laying on my desk.

Any places for me to look to change this behavior?  I've looked in Apple Music but not sure where to go next.

Comment: Does the jabra have any touch controls you might accidentally be pressing when you move it? I have similar behaviour with a bose 700nc which has play/pause/skip/volume touch controls on the right earcup. When I take of the headset I often touch the play control by accident, which launches apple music.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lion and later: Stop auto launching iTunes on Bluetooth headset connect?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/115990/lion-and-later-stop-auto-launching-itunes-on-bluetooth-headset-connect)

Comment: My laptop does not had a CD/DVD player so that option does not work and the iTunesPatch script that's referenced "does not work on macOS High Sierra and later versions" (from their website last updated in 2016) so no luck there

Comment: What about the other questions on this site that refer to the same issue? I'm on a phone now, so browsing is a bit cumbersome,so I can't look them up for you.

Comment: Seems it was a Jabra application setting - see my updated question.

Comment: Nice find! Perhaps you can post it as your answer instead of an update, as it solves your problem? It's perfectly fine to answer your own question, as that makes it easier for future users to find the solution to this problem.

Comment: Please post your findings as an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jabra has an application, [Jabra Direct](https://www.jabra.com/supportpages/jabra-evolve2-65), that gives some control over how the device works.  That app does not give you control over what the buttons do but it does have this setting:

[image]

I've changed that to off and all sees to be good, no more Apple Music when I move the headset.

Of note, there is an unusual part of the installation around a System Extension that's signed by a Jabra employee and not Jabra. It's unnerving at first but after a little research it is in fact from Jabra.

Comment: This option does not exist now.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I couldn't see the setting listed above by Jason. I have the same Jabra Evolve2 65 headset, but I had an older version of Jabra Direct I believe from a previous headset. I'm on a Mac, so I first had to delete that old Jabra Direct because the option to upgrade it continuously failed with the installer it was linking to (https://macuninstallguides.com/remove-jabra-direct-on-mac.html). Then, I downloaded the latest version for Mac here: https://www.jabra.com/software-and-services/jabra-direct

After some firmware upgrades to the headset and dongle I can see the setting above. So far I'm not having this problem with iTunes seemingly randomly starting up, but it does seem plausible that this motion sensor setting is a solution.

[image: Jabra Direct - Jabra Evolve2 65 Settings]

*** UPDATE ***
Spoke too soon. I stepped away from my machine with the headset and it happened again. Now trying with the aforementioned setting turned off.

Answer (score 0):

I installed NoTunes to fix a similar issue where Music starts up automatically.

https://github.com/tombonez/noTunes

Then I added NoTunes to the login items so that it starts automatically.

There is a similar question here about it:
https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/427818/498607

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/338246)

Answer (score 0):

From the Jabra Evolve2 65 User Guide:
"Play/Stop Music - Alternatively, the headset will pause music when it is placed on a flat surface, and will resume music when lifted from a flat surface."