# Disable Apple Music starting when Bluetooth connects

Tags: bluetooth, apple-music

I'm using macOS is 11.6 and have tried all the other ways listed from as far back as 8 years until recently.  Most of those methods don't work/options are no longer visible.

Looked at deleting it from the Applications folder but it isn't really there (try `ls /Applications/M*` to see what I mean).

I just want it to go away.  I don't use it, I don't want it, I don't need it.  Happens every time Bluetooth connects, earbuds, radio, doesn't matter.

Found the app, can't delete it.

```
sudo mv /System/Applications/Music.app/ /System/Applications/NoMusic.app
mv: rename /System/Applications/Music.app/ to /System/Applications/NoMusic.app: Operation not permitted

/System/Applications/Music.app/Contents/MacOS $ sudo mv Music NoMusic
mv: rename Music to NoMusic: Operation not permitted

/System/Applications/Music.app/Contents/MacOS $ sudo chmod -x Music
chmod: Unable to change file mode on Music: Operation not permitted
```

Comment: I wonder what causes that behavior?  Have several Macs in the home (both work and personal) and have never seen this behavior.  Did this just start happening after an update or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Music** in **macOS Big Sur** resides on a *cryptographically signed read-only volume* and why you cannot by default delete it. With the right modifications technically it can be done, however, due to the fact and an *update/upgrade* of **macOS** will just put it back, and or breaking the seal prevents the use of **FileVault**, and having other options, I'm not going to get into the details of the technicality.

If you do not find the direct cause of the issue and are unable to fix it without some sort of an easy settings change, then I offer the following as either a temporary workaround or ongoing one until such time you find another solution to your issue.

I've never experienced that issue, however if I did, here is what I do as a temporary/ongoing workaround...

I'd install [**Hammerspoon**](https://www.hammerspoon.org) and add the following *example* **Lua** *code* to its **init.lua** *file*:

```lua
function applicationMusicWatcher(appName, eventType, appObject)
    if (eventType == hs.application.watcher.launching) then
        if (appName == "Music") then
            local op, stat, typ, ec = hs.execute([["/usr/bin/killall" "Music"]])
            if not (ec == 0) then
                msg = "An error occurred terminating Music."
                hs.notify.new({title="Hammerspoon", informativeText=msg}):send()
            end                     
        end
    end
end
appMusicWatcher = hs.application.watcher.new(applicationMusicWatcher)
appMusicWatcher:start()
```

**Notes:**

This will immediately terminate **Music** upon it starting to launch.

You may/will see the icon for **Music** bounce briefly in the **Dock**, although I would think that is better than manually having to close it each time.

<sup>I am not affiliated with the developers of **Hammerspoon**, just a satisfied user of the product.</sup>

Comment: I put this in ~/.hammerspoon/init.lua and the Music App no longer pops up all over my screen!  Thanks!  I used homebrew to install hammerspoon.

Comment: @boatcoder, RE: "I used homebrew to install hammerspoon" --  I hope you didn't install **Homebrew** just to install **Hammerspoon** as it's available for direct download from its website. Anyway, hope you find some other uses for **Hammerspoon** as I do use it for several different things.

Comment: I'm a developer, I use homebrew for LOTS of things....

Comment: This was the fix that worked for me on Big Sur.

Answer (score 5):

This is unfortunately standard behavior on macOS since Catalina.

Try running [noTunes](https://github.com/tombonez/noTunes):

> noTunes is a macOS application that will prevent iTunes or Apple Music
> from launching.
>
> Simply launch the noTunes app and iTunes/Music will no longer be able
> to launch. For example, when bluetooth headphones reconnect.

You might also consider [filing feedback with Apple](https://www.apple.com/feedback/).

Comment: RE: "This is unfortunately standard behavior on macOS since Catalina." -- Personally I find that not to be true on my 16" BMP running **macOS Catalina** (and without using the workaround in my answer as I do use **Music**).  I have never had **Music** automatically launch just by a **Bluetooth** device connecting to my **Mac**.

Comment: Filing feedback with apple when they make money on the bad behavior is a bit like pissing in the wind.  They really don't care.  If they made money off of third party cookies, you wouldn't be able to block them.  They money selling music and movies which is why a free year of Apple TV allows you to "purchase" movies and TV from them.

Comment: `noTunes` stopped Apple Music from launching when I press the stop/start button on my Bluetooth headphones.  Thanks for posting this elegant solution to a stupid Apple annoyance. I especially like that it installs through `homebrew`, which makes me feel safer about it.